# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: pipeline for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple jenkinsfile as shown below:

```
pipeline { 
agent any 
stages {
    stage('Build') { 
        steps { 
            sh './mvnw compile' 
        }
    }
    stage('Test'){
        steps {
            sh './mvnw test'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and a simple Jenkins pipeline with repository URL and credentials( I can confirm that the credentials are fine because otherwise jenkins gives error rightaway).

But when I run this pipeline, I get error  as follows:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: pipeline for class: 
groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
at 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.
SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:130)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall
(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall
 (ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.
dispatchOrArg
(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.
fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
    at 
 com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive
 (ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org 
 .codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use
 (GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use
(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101
(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.
 lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.
runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0
(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk
(CpsThread.java:174)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run
(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200
(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call
(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call
(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call
(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run
(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run
(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run
(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am new to groovy, but this seems to be strange. I tried to follow other questions on stackoverflow but with no help.

If anybody has encountered this before, your guidance will help and will be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot,
-Pankaj

Comment: Is this an older installation? Can you make sure that the [pipeline-model-api](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-model-api) plugin is installed?

Comment: Yes pipeline-model-api 2.16 is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems the plugin issue of "Script Security Plugin 1.45".
In my case, the issue was resolved by updating it to 1.46.

Comment: Thanks Minehiko. upgrading to 1.46 for the script security plugin did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by downgrading Script Security Plugin. You can find it in Manage Plugins. As answered by Minehiko Nohara.